# Bigquery: Group timestamp by month

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new in bigquery and I can show timestamp like this.

```
select event_timestamp as timestamp1
          FROM `alive-ios.analytics_160092165.events_201810*` 
          GROUP BY timestamp1
```

Output is like this. How can I group those by month? Is it like this?
https://www.pascallandau.com/bigquery-snippets/convert-timestamp-date-datetime-to-different-timezone/

I try with to_char, DATE , etc and it is not okay.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like you want the [`TIMESTAMP_TRUNC` function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp_trunc), e.g.

```
select TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(event_timestamp, MONTH) as timestamp1
FROM `alive-ios.analytics_160092165.events_201810*`
GROUP BY timestamp1
```

Answer (score 3):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SELECT 
  FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m', TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)) month, 
  COUNT(1) events
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY month
```

Note: most likely you want to count events for each month, so I added `COUNT(1)`, but you can add whatever you need  - like SUM(amount) for example if you want to calculate some metric named `value`

Also, your wildcard expression is build in such a way that it will have only events for month of October 2018 (assuming the table name represent time of event) - so you will need to relax a little you wildcard expression to (for example) `alive-ios.analytics_160092165.events_2018*` so you will have events for months of whole 2018 year

Above assuming your event_timestamp is represented in microseconds
If in reality they are of TIMESTAMP type  - just remove use of TIMESTAMP_MICROS() function

Answer (score 0):

Building on Elliott's example, I think you need to convert the value to a timestamp first. From your example data I think you need TIMESTAMP_MICROS

[TIMESTAMP_MICROS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp_micros)

```
select TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp), MONTH) as timestamp1
FROM `alive-ios.analytics_160092165.events_201810*`
GROUP BY timestamp1
```